# Griffel - CSS in JS - Cannot overwrite child class rule on parent element hover

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, css-in-js, griffel.js

I'm using Griffel https://griffel.js.org/ for the first time and I am struggling to achieve this simple thing. By default this button is hidden and when the user hover's over the parent I want to  make the child visible.

I am using React so I have this button component inside the parent div.

```
const styles = useStyles();

<div className={styles.userContainer}>
  <Button className={styles.removeUserButton} />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  removeUserButton: {
    display: 'none'
  },
  userContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fefefe',
    '&:hover': {
      '& removeUserButton': {
        display: 'inline-block'
      } 
    }
  }
})
```

I was not sure if it will know what the removeUserButton class is so I also tried by making it variable. So I added:

```
const removeUserClassName = 'removeUserButton';
```

on top of the file and then in CSS:

```
[removeUserClassName]: {
  display: 'none'
},
userContainer: {
  backgroundColor: '#fefefe',
  '&:hover': {
    [`& ${removeUserClassName}`]: {
      display: 'inline-block'
    }
  }
}
```

But this still does not work.
And in case you are wondering I have also tried the first piece of code by adding . before removeUserButton.

Has anyone used Griffel and knows how to handle this?
Appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

Here is a sandbox I created:
https://codesandbox.io/s/griffel-hover-issue-gwx1sj

Comment: I can try to create a sandbox, issue is that hover part does not work. Also this worked fine when I was using regular CSS modules. Right now I am in a process of moving code to Griffel and cannot get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to use a classname that is in your configuration (`removeUserClassName`). Yet, Griffel uses dynamic class names. So you'll need to use a different selector.

You can see the nature of the dynamic class names [in this playground example](https://griffel.js.org/try-it-out/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbziAhgawKYGUYE8A2GAzgDRxEAW0MFKAdgCZFwC%2BcAZlBCHAOQACAcyjB27DPgD0AY2gZeAbgBQSjAA9IsOAwzsUAV3zxUmHAWIAKBErhwoGEBABuGAKpEMUAEL6YMCHQAXIg2ttrARGD4KLjBvHQB8iShLMm2%2Bh5QAMIBMCjAdJ7B1mFwAO7ADDRxAIwArAAMYGq8aWEUGMCCFDBxjc2tobYARijSaMIQ%2Bow5%2BNBxw9Hjg6W8gVQuUGshpba8AGRww77%2BdNtIDBFRMXEF%2BAUYALSLEMusbaWj45PTDLPzfEW%2BiSQ3eKWSLAAlMogA).

[Here is a working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gqmbg4?file=src%2FuseStyles.js,src%2FApp.js) that uses the `button` as selector rather than class name and it works fine.

Here is the code for reference:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@griffel/react';

export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  removeUserButton: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  userContainer: {
    width: '150px',
    height: '50px',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    ':hover': {
      '& button': { display: 'inline-block' },
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo here, in my code I do have quotes.

Comment: I have added quotes to the code in my question

Comment: I've changed the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah works with a button, guess if I cannot figure it with the class I can change code to this

Comment: There are many, many ways to use CSS selectors that can allow you to select any element very precisely. Using the classname is unnecessary really.

Comment: yes class is just more specific

Comment: you are wrong about that, but that's ok.

Comment: i really appreciate your help but I was looking for a solution relative to a class. I will still accept your answer but I am not sure why will you say that I am wrong? Isn't a class more specific than a button tag?

Comment: [Here is a good guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#how_is_specificity_calculated) - you'll see that if you want absolute specificity you should use an `id` attribute. But like I said, you're approach is OK. I just don't think you'll be able to pull it off using a class name that does not exist at run time. If there is an API way of determining the dynamic class name that is generated, that would be the approach to take.

Comment: Isn't this type of thing the use case that `resetStyles()` is designed to support?

Comment: not sure reading about it now, I just started using griffel 2 days ago :-)